# Как адаптировать фоновое изображение на сайте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пример: currency.com

Как адаптировать фоновое изображение так, чтобы при любом изменении ширины и длины устройства самое главное содержимое картинки было видно на HTML и CSS?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Background position 50% 50% или 32% на 76% в зависимости от того, где важная часть

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]